# 'OR' CLAUSE INSIDE IF CONDITIONAL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a function in oracle. It seems it is not possible to do something like this:

```
IF (VAR1 IS NULL OR LENGTH(TRIM(VAR2))) = 0 THEN
    -- do something;
END IF;
```

How can I use 'OR' clause inside if. I want to ask for two possible conditions in the same line using if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you place your parenthesis correctly:

```
IF (VAR1 IS NULL OR LENGTH(TRIM(VAR2)) =0) THEN
-- do something;
END IF;
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I thought it was related with the 'or'.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get your parenthesis lined up. Your last right paren is in the wrong place.

```
IF (VAR1 IS NULL OR LENGTH(TRIM(VAR2)) = 0) THEN
    -- do something;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can check multiple condition In a single line with the IF statement.But parenthesis should be place correctly.

See the syntax:

```
IF (VAR1 IS NULL OR LENGTH(TRIM(VAR2)) = 0) THEN
  do something
End if;
```